# Есть ли команда для быстрого перехода в окно иерархии проекта по открытому в редакторе файлу?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, jetbrains

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли команда для быстрого перехода в окно иерархии проекта по открытому в редакторе файлу?

Т. е. вначале я выбираю файл в окне проекта, он открывается в окне редактора. В окне редактора есть также другие открытые файлы.

Возможно ли, выбрав другой открытый файл в редакторе кода, быстро понять где он находится в иерархии проекта?

До этого работал в 1С и там указанное действие выполняла команда  ctrl+T (Tree).

Comment: Кнопка в виде "прицела" над панелью проекта

Comment: Спасибо. Я был недостаточно внимателен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, далее нажать <kbd>1</kbd>. Либо воспользоваться кнопкой прицела:

[image: скриншот]

Кроме того, в настройках IDE есть опция [Always Select Opened File](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#scroll_to_from_source), если она включена, то в дереве всегда будет отображаться текущий открытый файл, а кнопка прицела будет отсутствовать:

[image: скриншот]